# How do I divide results from OMDb API to table?

Tags: javascript, database

I am currently working with the [OMDb API](http://omdbapi.com/) and managed to get some data out of it. Right now I am searching the movie database by the title and year of release, and able to get actors in a one "block".

**Here are the two problems I am facing though:**

1. How to divide all the actors to their own table rows?
2. Is it possible to limit the search for TV-series only and replace 'Year' with 'Season' or so?

My **JavaScript** goes:

```
$(function(){
  var $Search = $('form'), $Results = $('#results');
  $Results.hide();

  $Search.on('submit', function(p_oEvent){
    var sUrl, sMovie, sYear, oData;
    p_oEvent.preventDefault();
    sMovie = $Search.find('#title').val();
    sYear = $Search.find('#year').val();
    sUrl = encodeURI('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + sMovie + '&y=' + sYear +     '');

    $.ajax(sUrl, {
      complete: function(p_oXHR, p_sStatus){
        oData = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);
        console.log(oData);
        $Results.find('.actors').text(oData.Actors);
        $Results.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And my **HTML** where it's all being printed out:

```
<div id="browse">
  <h1>Search for a TV-Series</h1>
  <form>
    <label>
        <input id="title" type="text" name="series" placeholder="Name of the Series" />
        <input id="year" type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year" />
    </label>
    <button>Go!</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="results">
  <table>
    <tr class="heading">
      <th>Actors</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="actors"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any help and advice will be welcome!

Comment: Just loop over the actors from the Api response and create `<tr>` tags and append them to the page.

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(oData);` returns please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display each actor on their own row, you need to `split` the comma delimited string of actors the API returns back, iterate over the list, and append each actor to the page. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3838/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="browse">
  <h1>Search for a TV-Series</h1>
  <form>
    <label>
        <input id="title" type="text" name="series" placeholder="Name of the Series" />
        <input id="year" type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year" />
    </label>
    <button>Go!</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="results">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  var $Search = $('form'), $Table = $('table');
  $Table.hide();

  $Search.on('submit', function(p_oEvent){
    var actors = [], sUrl, sMovie, sYear, oData;
    p_oEvent.preventDefault();
    sMovie = $Search.find('#title').val();
    sYear = $Search.find('#year').val();
    sUrl = encodeURI('https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + sMovie + '&y=' + sYear +     '');

    $.ajax(sUrl, {
      complete: function(p_oXHR, p_sStatus){
        oData = $.parseJSON(p_oXHR.responseText);
        actors = oData.Actors.split(',');

        $Table.html(
           '<tr class="heading"><th>Actors</th></tr>'
        );
        actors.forEach(function(actor) {
            $Table.append(
               '<tr><td class="actors">' + actor + '</td</tr>'      
            );
        });
        $Table.show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

To answer your second question, yes it is possible to search by season and TV-series only. Here is an example below.

`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=2&Episode=1&type=series`

The issue with this API call is you have to search by `Episode`, where I imagine you may want to know every character within the entire season. In order to do that you will have to make the API call without the `Episode` parameter and then use id's that are returned back to retrieve every episode.

Comment: Thank you for the specific answer! This should be it, but I'd like to ask few things: Is there some sort of a limit on the API side which only gives 4 actors at a time? Also, how can I perform a fresh search each time. Now if I do a search and do another just after, it leaves the previous results to the table as well?

Comment: I updated the answer so that it removes previous results. There seems to be a limit of 4 actors, but I don't see any documentation about it.

Comment: Thank you, working like a charm! Shame that it limits (or at least seems to limit) the results, but I'll get along with this.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Jamesking56 mentioned in the comment, you only need to iterate through actors from the response, and create new table row for each. However, from what I see, actors are returned in a single string. Because of that, you need to split actors by ", " delimiter, and iterate through the resulting array. See [JS String split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [JS Array forEach()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp).
2. You can see in [OMDb API Changelog](http://omdbapi.com/#changeLog) that it's possible to search for particular season and episode:

   > 5/10/15 Season+Episode search parameters added: [http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game of Thrones&Season=1&Episode=1](http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Game%20of%20Thrones&Season=1&Episode=1)

   So use it as you wish. I don't know whether it's possible to limit search only to TV Series, but "Season" is mostly not used for Movies anyway, so you should get only Series by using that query.